# In $TD(\lambda)$, is there a way to choose an effective $\lambda$ based on the environment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference

In $TD(\lambda)$, is there a way to choose an effective $\lambda$ based on the environment?

Comment: Not really. Try a few values and see what works.

Comment: In my experience, people just try a few values. Try low, then try high, then try middle.

Comment: Related: [When are Monte Carlo methods preferred over temporal difference ones?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/336974/)